# cordova https/SSL issue in ios

Tags: ios, cordova, ssl, https

My cordova app needs to invoke a web services which is running in PHP. 
All of the web services url's are "**https**". I am getting the below error when I tried to run the app with https url in iphone/ipad device.

I tried to debug the app using Safari web Inspector. I am getting below error.

```
Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “api.xyz.com” which could put your confidential information at risk.
```

Need some help to resolve this.

Comment: You read the cordova whitelisting guide already? https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide `access-origin` and things like that is all set correct?

Comment: Use a trusted certificate or don't use https

Comment: Thanks for your response. This was because of trusted certificate issue.

Comment: could you elaborate? Maybe write an answer and mark it answered, because i have the same problem as you had